# Why my windowtester tests are failing in jenkins server slaves

Tags: maven, jenkins, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, window-tester

My Window Tester UI Tests(All the tests which has error dialogs and error messages in in RCP Application) are failing in Jenkins server, but they are passing in my local machine.

Is there anything to do with machine configurations, like based one executors?

if the machine configurations doesn't matter why they are not failing in my local machine?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not running your Jenkins server in a desktop session, meaning that it does not have access to your GUI (e.g. it can't launch anything that pops-up a window or a dialog).

So you either need to start the Jenkins master manually from the command line or allow it to access the GUI if it's run as a service.

See also these two related topics:

- [How to run GUI tests on a jenkins windows slave without remote desktop connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19441324/how-to-run-gui-tests-on-a-jenkins-windows-slave-without-remote-desktop-connectio)
- https://serverfault.com/questions/285065/gui-tests-in-hudson-jenkins-on-windows