# Jenkins run Selenium tests on background

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jenkins, windows-server-2012

I have Jenkins installed on a Windows Server 2012 machine running my selenium tests written in Java, but when I run the test I cannot see any browser opening (the tests won't fail at start but at some point the interaction fails, also all the screenshots are black).

I've read some guides and I've tried to install a slave node on the same machine but the result didn't changed.

Any suggestion?

I've noticed that the browser is opened with a different user (system) and maybe this could be the problem.

Comment: Selenium WebDriver? Internet Explorer driver?

Comment: @engineer I'm using Selenium WebDriver and the IE driver too

Comment: check you are running the tests with admin privileges - possible cause of black in screen shot

Comment: I ran jenkins from command prompt as "java -jar jenkins.war" instead of the windows installer version. Now I can see my browser based tests being executed.

Comment: @rajNishKuMar but when I do that, all the other jobs disappears (we have about 30 other jobs running on jenkins).

Comment: You might need to change the jenkins home directory in configuration when you run it as different user. See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24529629/3623345) Q&A and the other linked Q&A there.

Comment: I resolved installing a slave on the same machine of the master (opening the ports)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really didn't give a lot of info, but here's some thoughts:

1. If you're using Chrome or IE, you'll need the appropriate server app available on your path. Download those [here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/).
2. Consider running your tests on a different system from the Jenkins server. There's enough going on that system already. Use RemoteWebDriver on a small VM or unused system somewhere. Good overview docs for it are [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/docs/remote.html).