# Winium and Jenkins without Remote Desktop

Tags: c#, jenkins, winium

I'm trying to automatize some tests with Jenkins and Winium for `GUI` Application on remote machine. If I try to execute tests on the machine with activated `RDP` all work fine, while if `RDP` is dis-activated I have the error 
"Some simulated input commands were not sent successfully.

The most common reason for this happening are the security features of Windows including User Interface Privacy Isolation (`UIPI`). Your application can only send commands to applications of the same or lower elevation. Similarly certain commands are restricted to Accessibility/UIAutomation applications. Refer to the project home page and the code samples for more information.
  `Origine=Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework`".

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's a specific of Jenkins agents - they don't create normal UI session. So you need to use workarounds for testing GUI applications. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19452140/10721592) answer as example.

Note: possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19441324/how-to-run-gui-tests-on-a-jenkins-windows-slave-without-remote-desktop-connectio) question.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried workaround but i have the same problem. In my case i'm trying to start test on jenkins master machine.

Comment: Did you tried to check also "the security features of Windows including User Interface Privacy Isolation (UIPI)"?

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: @G.Petruzziello Have you found the answer?